# Problem with app store connect with individual account

Tags: ios, flutter, macos, app-store

I have an individual apple developer account and assigned a task to other developer to upload app to my account but every time he tried he failed although i added him as admin in my users section how can he submit app from his mac without adding my credentials ???

Answer (score 0):

He/she wouldn't do that without a pair of `Distribution Certificate` and `Distribution Provisioning`. If this is the case and you don't want to public your credentials. You could do this alternative way:

1. Create a Distribution Certificate on [developer program](https://developer.apple.com/). Then download and click on it to add this certificate to your Keychain on MacOS.

[image]

---

2. Back to your developer program and create a `Provisioning Profile`

> Profiles -> Plus button -> Distribution section -> App Store Connect/Mac App Store Connect

[image]

---

The final step is exporting the certificate (.p12) from Keychain and the provisioning profile above to other developers.

[image]

Now he/she will be able to configure `Signing` manually:

> Xcode -> Project -> Build Settings -> Signing